# Change state object variable from form input - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, forms, state

I have a state:

```
state = {
   obj1: {
       name: "",
       message: "",
   }
}
```

I have a form:

```
<form>
<input id={obj1.name} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
<input id={obj1.message} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
</form>
```

on handleChange:

```
handleChange(e) {
    const {id, value} = e.target
    this.setState({[id]:value});

}
```

Instead of updating the obj1 in the state, it will create a new state variable and obj1 doesn't get updated. [id] : value works on state variables that are not objects. How can I achieve setting a new state in an object through a form change?

Comment: Why is the second input field referencing obj2? Based on your question, you have only one object, so there shouldn't be an obj2 right?

Comment: Yes, that was an mistake during the writing portion of this code. I'll have that changed.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to update an object with a string? Because based on this code, both input fields have the same value of an empty string. So which property of the object are you trying to update? I don't get what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: On user Input change for the ID obj1.name and obj.2, I want to realize the changes in the state object so I can use that data elsewhere. For example. When an user enters in a name in the input id=(obj1.name) I would like this.state.obj1.name to have the same data.

Comment: Oh... then that's a completely different thing than what you're doing here. I'll draft a demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the thing to take away is - there's a second version of the `setState` method that uses a callback with the old state as a parameter. It goes something like this:

```
this.setState(state => ({
  // ... Do your manipulation here
}))
```

With this, you'll be able to "update" the state without replacing it. Try to figure it out yourself using just this hint :)

If you could, kudos! You're awesome! Check out the sandbox of what I did and let's know if you did it differently. If you couldn't, no worries, you're definitely awesome! Still checkout the sandbox here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-https-rtwr7?file=/src/ClassState.js

Comment: Hi!
While you were working on this awesome solution, I had mine done this way:

let obj= {...this.state.obj, [id]: value};
        this.setState( {obj}, ()=> {
            console.log(this.state);
        });
This is called an object spread, where I create an new obj based on the state object. Then I will pass the name variables into the new obj.

Comment: Yeah, this definitely works too, I thought of this and it's nice. There's always many ways to solve the same problem. It's just the callback with the old state as a parameter is the official way of doing it. Awesome solution though. :). P.S please consider marking the answer accepted if it worked for you and you learned anything from it. Thanks.